# How to Raise SIGTERM in Windows

Tags: c, windows, signals

I'd appreciate it if you could tell us how to trigger SIGTERM on windows.
If you can, please give me some sample code.

Comment: You can use `raise` (no sample code needed, it really is as simple as reading the documentation), but no one uses signals on Windows except for POSIX compatibility. Why do you think you need this? What are you trying to do? Can you give us some more context?

Comment: And if you're trying to send a SIGTERM from one process to another process, that's not possible, Windows doesn't have inter-process signals.  You'll need to use some other form of IPC.

Answer (score 4):

Use the **raise** function:

```
int ret;
ret = raise(SIGTERM);
```

Comment: He asks about `SIGTERM`. (Which is good, because `SIGINT` is not supported for Win32 applications.)

Comment: Thanks, Cody.  Fixed it.